# PHP Google Login api restrict to only one domain

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, return

I have managed to get the login button to work on my localhost using oAuth 2.0. I have looked for other solutions like trying to edit the OAUTH2.php file to include a hd parameter. Here is how it looks:

```
  public function createAuthUrl($scope) {
     $params = array(
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'redirect_uri' => $this->client->getClassConfig($this, 'redirect_uri'),
    'client_id' => $this->client->getClassConfig($this, 'client_id'),
    'scope' => $scope,
    'access_type' => $this->client->getClassConfig($this, 'access_type'),
    'approval_prompt=' . urlencode($this->approvalPrompt),
    'hd=domain.com'
);

// Prefer prompt to approval prompt.
if ($this->client->getClassConfig($this, 'prompt')) {
  $params = $this->maybeAddParam($params, 'prompt');
} else {
  $params = $this->maybeAddParam($params, 'approval_prompt');
}
$params = $this->maybeAddParam($params, 'login_hint');
$params = $this->maybeAddParam($params, 'hd');
$params = $this->maybeAddParam($params, 'openid.realm');
$params = $this->maybeAddParam($params, 'include_granted_scopes');



// If the list of scopes contains plus.login, add request_visible_actions
// to auth URL.
$rva = $this->client->getClassConfig($this, 'request_visible_actions');
if (strpos($scope, 'plus.login') && strlen($rva) > 0) {
    $params['request_visible_actions'] = $rva;
}

if (isset($this->state)) {
  $params['state'] = $this->state;
}
return self::OAUTH2_AUTH_URL . "?" . http_build_query($params, '', '&');
}
```

As you can see I tried adding the hd parameter in the $params array, but it still let me login with my normal gmail account. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your domain is a Google Apps domain, you can restrict the allowed user domains by doing the following.

**1. Restrict GAE application referrals to a specific domain**

Developers Console --> App Engine --> Settings --> Application Settings --> Edit --> In Google Authentication section, choose 'Google Apps domain', enter the domain name.

**2. Connect GAE application to your Google Apps Domain**

On your Google Admin console for your Google Apps Domain, add your application as a new Google AppEngine service.

Also, it seems that Google will provide your server with the ID token directly. However, if this is not the case, please validate the ID token as per Google's [OpenID Connect Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect?hl=en#validatinganidtoken), which includes verifying that the `hd` claim is correct.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't find the settings on the developer console. I made a web application on the google developer console, but I cannot find the settings or application settings. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @DanZoe, if your domain is not a Google Apps domain, you will have to implement the login feature on your own. If there are Authentication APIs available, you can just use the appropriate libraries. Otherwise, you may have to setup your own login system and verify that the user has a valid email.

Comment: @DanZoe Please note that a [Google Apps Domain](https://apps.google.com/) is a paid feature from Google that a company needs to sign up for e.g. if a company decides to pay Google to run their website company.com. Users will then have the email user@company.com. Hotmail cannot be a google apps domain unfortunately

Comment: @DanZoe ok, have you set the Google Apps domains as described in the answer above? If you do so, and leave the 'hd' parameter in your code, you should be able to limit users from other domains from signing up.

Comment: @DanZoe unfortunately you must own the domain / request permission from the owners in order to restrict your app to the Google App domain. To do so you will have to enter your app id as a new application in the Google Admin console of your Google App domain. Sorry that I missed this part out, will edit it into the answer.